# android getting json object without array

Tags: php, android, json

How to get JSON object without array in android?

```
   {"advertisementid":"1","advertisment_imei_id":"1","advertisment_date":"18-11-2013 11:04:48","advertisment_title":"Test","advertisment_content":"Welcome","advertisment_image":"Water lilies.jpg","advertisment_video":"funnysarda_ieC8LUbm.mp4","imei":"Test123"}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to get json objects using above example. @gunar.

Answer (score 0):

Use gson library.

Object Examples

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

(Serialization)
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

`(DeSerialization)
BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);`